# How to write a code which can decrease the range of the answer until we get the right value?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I want to write a code which can help me decrease the range of answer until i find it.For example,S=0:0.001:1;and i have to find a value which its square will be the 0.09,that is,x^2=0.09,and the answer is 0.3

Now,if every time i guess median,that is ,

First time i guess "0.5",but 0.5^2=0.25 ,not 0.09,so the range become S=0:0.001:0.5

Second time i guess "0.25",but 0.25^2=0.0625 ,not 0.09.so the range become S=0.25:0.001:0.5

Third time i guess (0.25+0.5)/2=0.375,but 0.375^2=0.140625 ,not 0.09,so the range become S=0.25:0.001:0.375

So the range will keep decreasing  until i find the answer,and one of  upper bound and lower bound of the range will be my wrong number which i just guess.but i don't know how to modify the code

My original code

```
S=0:0.001:1;
x=0.5;
y=x^2;%not 0.09

S=0:0.001:x
q=0.25;
y=q^2;%not 0.09

S=q:0.001:x
w=0.375;
y=w^2%not 0.09

S=q:0.001:w %S=0.25:0.001:0.375
e=0.3125;
y=e^2 %not 0.09

S=e:0.001:w;
r=0.34;
y=r^2 %not 0.09
   .
   .
   .
```

until i found that y=0.09,so i can know the answer,however,this code is too long,i want to write a while or for loop to find the answer,does anyone know how to modify my code?

Answer (score 2):

This is called Biesection method.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method

There are many implementations you can re-use: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33748-bisection-method

Comment: so the method i use is not bisection search but Newton Raphson method?

Comment: You used bisection, which means cutting in two pieces. The most naive approach is to cut in half. Newton Raphson method bisects differently, and converges faster.